# Why does the error message not show for the first try, but works fine for the other?

Tags: c#, try-catch

Can someone please tell me why the first try catch is not showing an error message when the user inputs invalid format of data, i.e inputs integar instead of string. If I input numbers instead of letters, the program just accepts it and moves forward.
The other try catch for age is working fine.

```
public void add_passenger()
    {
        // Defining variables for name and age to be input
        string name;
        int age;

        //Show message on a clean, new screen
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("==> Welcome aboard <==");
        Console.WriteLine(" Please follow instructions to add yourself as a passenger ");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        
        // Ask user to input name
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" Your name: ");
            //Try and catch in case the user inputs wrong format
            try
            {
                name = Console.ReadLine();
                break;
            }
            catch //This doesn't work
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" Wrong input format. Please try again and input a rider.");
                continue;
            }
        }
        
        // Ask user to input age
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" Your age: ");
            //Try and catch in case the user inputs wrong format
            try
            {
                age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                break;
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" Wrong input format. Please write an integer.");
                continue;
            }
        }

        // Search the array for an empty slot to input the new passenger into
        for (int i = 0; i < passengers.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (passengers[i] == null)
            {
                passengers[i] = new Passagerare(name, age);
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                continue;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(""); 
        Console.WriteLine(" You have now boarded the bus. Welcome aboard!" );
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
```

Comment: The line of code… `name = Console.ReadLine();` … will accept any value “including” numbers. A number can also be a valid `string`. Since the code is reading into a `string` variable `name`, then all values are accepted. What would be considered an invalid value for `name`?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I wanted the name to only be able to store alphabets or letters, not numbers. I think I need to do a bit of research for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first try/catch block is working properly as well.  It's up to you, the developer to determine what value a string can contain in order for it to be valid or invalid.

In terms of the language, both "john doe" and "123151" are valid strings (the second one is just a string representation of digits).  Keep in mind that the code interprets these two very differently:

1. "123151"
2. 123151

The first is a string with the value "123151".
The second is an integer with the value 123151.

When you read from the console.ReadLine() function into a string variable, you will get a string value of whatever value is input.

What I would suggest, moving forward, is that you add some sort of programming to verify that the value that is input is more like the value your program is expecting.  For example, if you're not expecting the string to have any numbers in it, you could check the string for integer values, and throw the exception if any are found.  You might even use Regular Expressions to help identify integers or other invalid values.